# Set value from database to textbox based on search by id

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Please help me to solve the case.
I have an code below :

```
<script>
    function getXMLHTTP() {
        var xmlhttp = false;    
        try{
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try{
                xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            catch(e){
                try{
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                catch(e1){
                    xmlhttp=false;
                }
            }
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

    function getCity(url, id1) {
        var req = getXMLHTTP(url);
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (req.readyState == 4) {
                    // only if "OK"
                    if (req.status == 200) {
                        document.getElementById(id1).value=req.responseText;    
                        // document.getElementById(id2).value=req.responseText;
                    } else {
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
                    }
                }
            }
            req.open("GET", url, true);
            req.send(null);
        }
    }
</script>

<?php       
    echo "
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class='td'><input type='text' size='6' name='kode_barang" ."' maxlength='6' onchange='javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();' onkeyup='getCity(\"search.php?kode_barang=\"+this.value, \"nama_barang"  . "\",\"harga_barang"  . "\");' id='kode_barang'></td>
                <td class='td'><input type='text' size='22' name='nama_barang"  . "' id='nama_barang" . "' readonly tabindex='1'></td>
                <td class='td'><input type='text' size='22' name='harga_barang"  . "' id='harga_barang" . "' tabindex='1'></td>
        </tbody>
    ";
?>
```

search.php file :

```
include_once('config.php');

if (isset($_GET['kode_barang']))
{
    $qry = "SELECT nama_barang, harga_barang FROM t_barang WHERE kode_barang = '" . $_GET['kode_barang'] . "'";
    $sql = mysql_query($qry);

    $ary = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    echo $ary['nama_barang'];
    echo $ary['harga_barang'];
}
```

This is about how to find nama_barang and harga_barang based on kode_barang input.
Example if I input kode_barang in textbox kode_barang then in text_box nama_barang and harga_barang will set the information from database automatically.

I've tried in this code, but it set 2 information(nama_barang & harga_barang) in 1 textbox nama_barang. Should be set in each textbox.

So, my question is :
How to set the information nama_barang and harga_barang from database to each textbox ?

Appreciate with your helps.
Thank you.

Comment: Try to use jQuery or another javascript library to work with Ajax. That will help you implement the scenario simply.

Comment: @Muneer: How will that help OP? The problem stays the same. Or did you just see a AJAX request and no jQuery and had the immediate urge to post your comment?

Comment: @Amberlamps of course, I believe if code is minimized, then easy to troubleshoot. And it might help him in his future implementations as well.

Comment: @Muneer: OP does not need to troublshoot, because his code works fine. It is a matter of concept that OP is asking about. Minifying your code will not help in that case. Also, why would you ever include a whole framework for just one of its functions? This is even more ridiculous when you are fairly able to implement that same function yourself.

Comment: @Amberlamps ha ha ha... why you are chasing me? it is just a piece of comment I wanted to suggest him. If you want take. or leave it. and try to help him. why you are crying for nothing? you are so funny!!! :p

Comment: @Muneer: False feedback is very misleading. I want you to think before you write. This is a very legitimate platform. Also, keep in mind that jQuery is not the answer to everything.

Comment: @Amberlamps ok ok... I am very sorry sir, please give him the correct reply.

Comment: @Muneer: Why do you expect me to have the right answer to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace your getCity() function with the following one

```
  function getCity(url, id1, id2) {    
        var req = getXMLHTTP(url);
            if (req) {    
            req.onreadystatechange = function() {    
                if (req.readyState == 4) {    
                    // only if "OK"    
                    if (req.status == 200) {
            var res = JSON.parse(req.responseText);    
                        document.getElementById(id1).value=res.nama_barang;      
                        document.getElementById(id2).value=res.harga_barang;    
                    } else {    
                        alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);    
                    }    
                }    
            }

            req.open("GET", url, true);    
            req.send(null);    
        }    
 }
```

and replace the part of code in your search.php

from

```
$ary = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo $ary['nama_barang'];
echo $ary['harga_barang'];
```

to

```
$ary = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

echo json_encode($ary);
```

> The problem was, you are missing the ID of second text box in your
>   getCity() function.

### **Update for sending default Value**

replace the following part

```
if (isset($_GET['kode_barang']))
{
    $qry = "SELECT nama_barang, harga_barang FROM t_barang WHERE kode_barang = '" . $_GET['kode_barang'] . "'";
    $sql = mysql_query($qry);

    $ary = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

    echo $ary['nama_barang'];
    echo $ary['harga_barang'];
}
```

with

```
if (isset($_GET['kode_barang']))
{
    $qry = "SELECT nama_barang, harga_barang FROM t_barang WHERE kode_barang = '" . $_GET['kode_barang'] . "'";
    $sql = mysql_query($qry);

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0)
    {
      $ary = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

      echo json_encode($ary);
    }
    else
    {
       echo json_encode(array("nama_barang" => "", "harga_barang" => ""));
    } 
}
```

*** any way this is not the best practice as it make the data base request for each of your keyup event. but can help you solve.

Comment: This is exactly what I wrote in my answer! What is wrong with you?

Comment: that's a good answer. really thanks muneer. Now my problem solved. Sorry, when I try to input text, that show undefined in textbox until I complete the ID and show the information. Can I hide the information "undefined" ?

Comment: @DavidAlwis Yes, in your search.php. make a default array like this.. $default_res = array("nama_barang" => "", "harga_barang" => ""); and send it back to client when there are no result.

Comment: @Muneer: Dude, you are ridiculous! Please tell me, what you did differently than in my answer!

Comment: Yes @DavidAlwis I have given a fix in update of my answer, it can help you solve. but it is not the best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Change php file from:

```
echo $ary['nama_barang'];
echo $ary['harga_barang'];
```

to

```
echo json_encode($ary);
```

and change your JS-function from

```
document.getElementById(id1).value=req.responseText;    
document.getElementById(id2).value=req.responseText;
```

to

```
var response = JSON.parse(responseText);
document.getElementById(id1).value=response.nama_barang;    
document.getElementById(id2).value=response.harga_barang;
```

Comment: dear amberlamps, I've updated the code using your suggestions. but it still show in 1 textbox. that's the result : {"0":"LENOVO THINK CENTER","nama_barang":"LENOVO THINK CENTER","1":"7800000","harga_barang":"7800000"}

Comment: Do you send a value of `id2` to your `getCity()` function? For now you only have `getCity(url, id1)`. Maybe you need a signature like `getCity(url, id1, id2)` and do not forget to call the function with a second ID.

Comment: I have make it like this : <input type='text' size='6' name='kode_barang" ."' maxlength='6' onchange='javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();' onkeyup='getCity(\"search.php?kode_barang=\"+this.value, \"nama_barang"  . "\",\"harga_barang"  . "\");' id='kode_barang'>, is that true ?

Comment: Why are you concatenating the string? It is not necessary. Also, read my previous comment. Add `id2` to the parameters of your function like that `getCity(url, id1, id2)`

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("nama_barang").value=response.nama_barang; document.getElementById("harga_barang").value=response.harga_barang;` in your JS function then.

Comment: When you have `{"0":"LENOVO THINK CENTER","nama_barang":"LENOVO THINK CENTER","1":"7800000","harga_barang":"7800000"}` as response and did everything like I said and it still does not work, there might be different errors in you JS that are causing the whole thing to fail. I am sorry, but I cannot help your from here on out. You might wanna see your browser´s console for possible JS errors.

Comment: So, could you help me if I send you my code file by email maybe ?

Comment: I am sorry, but I cannot. You should be able to debug your code yourself. You can add the rendered HTML page to the end of your question and I see what I can do :)

Comment: sir, i've tried with this code: document.getElementById(id1).value=req.responseText; 
 document.getElementById(id2).value=req.responseText; value show now in each textbox, but the value double now, ex : LENOVO THINK CENTER7800000 in textbox nama barang, LENOVO THINK CENTER7800000 in textbox harga barang

Comment: Yes, I read sir. When I try your answer there's nothing effect. So I try with my as best I could.